# Remove table rows for given pattern in Java String

Tags: java, html, regex, string, pattern-matching

I want to remove all the rows having **N/A** as value is the last column of given html code (java string).

Please help me in getting correct regex/pattern code to remove all occurrences:

```html
<table class="overviewTable">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="6" class="header suite">
      <div class="suiteLinks">
                                        <a href="suite1_groups.html">Groups</a>
              </div>
      Test Automation
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="columnHeadings">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <th>Duration</th>
    <th>Passed</th>
    <th>Skipped</th>
    <th>Failed</th>
    <th>Pass Rate</th>
  </tr>
    
    <tr class="test">
    <td class="test">
      <a href="suite1_test14_results.html">Test Xyz</a>
    </td>
    <td class="duration">
      0.000s
    </td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>
    
        <td class="zero number">0</td>
    
        <td class="zero number">0</td>
    
    <td class="passRate">
            N/A
          </td>
  </tr>
    
    <tr class="test">
    <td class="test">
      <a href="suite1_test15_results.html">Test abc XYZ</a>
    </td>
    <td class="duration">
      0.000s
    </td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>
    
        <td class="zero number">0</td>
    
        <td class="zero number">0</td>
    
    <td class="passRate">
            N/A
          </td>
  </tr>
      
    <tr class="test">
    <td class="test">
      <a href="suite1_test17_results.html">TestAbcSuccess</a>
    </td>
    <td class="duration">
      77.582s
    </td>

        <td class="passed number">1</td>
    
        <td class="zero number">0</td>
    
        <td class="zero number">0</td>
    
    <td class="passRate">
            100%
          </td>
  </tr>
    
    <tr class="suite">
    <td colspan="2" class="totalLabel">Total</td>

        <td class="passed number">1</td>
    
        <td class="zero number">0</td>
    
        <td class="zero number">0</td>
    
    <td class="passRate suite">
            100%
          </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

This is index.html file of Java+Selenium+TestNG automation results.

Please help me in getting correct regex/pattern code to remove all occurrences from the above HTML.

These are my trials:

**1.**

```
fullHtmlStr = fullHtmlStr.replaceAll("(?<=<tr class=\"test\">).*?(?=N/A\n          </td>)", "");
```

**2.**

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("<tr class=\"test\">.*$.N/A\n          </td>", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL );
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(fullHtmlStr);
if (m.find())
   fullHtmlStr = m.replaceAll("");
```

(I don't have any knowledge of regex, so please forgive my incase these are totally wrong)

Attaching screenshots:

Screenshot Before Updation:
[image]

Screenshot After Updation:
[image]

Comment: @mplungjan - its not related to selenium, just assume it as pure Java code.

Comment: @DebanjanB - I have updated my trials above. Thanks.

Comment: @MukeshRajput `remove all the rows having N/A` from where?

Comment: @DebanjanB - Above attached HTML code is read by me as String in my java code, now I want to manipulate this string, so that all the rows containing N/A are removed from the string.

Comment: Are you sure just removing _all the rows containing N/A_ will suffice to your need as _String manipulating_ the _HTML DOM_ won't be preserve the _DOM_ structure?

Comment: @DebanjanB, 
I have added screenshots above, please have a look.

Comment: Well, regex is used for _String Manipulation_ but you seem to need to alter the _HTML DOM_. Aren't both the cases different?

Comment: @DebanjanB - Please treat this html code as String only, which is stored in `fullHtmlStr ` variable present in my trials above.
Now the thing is, I want to manipulate this string so that all the rows containing N/A are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestion by @little-santi, i have used jsoup html parser to manipulate the code, here is my code:

```
            Document document = Jsoup.parse(strText);
            for( org.jsoup.nodes.Element element : document.select("td:eq(5)")) {
                String content = element.getElementsMatchingOwnText("N/A").text();
                if(content.equalsIgnoreCase("N/A")) {
                    element = element.parent();
                    element.remove();
                }
            }
            strText = document.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I discourage you to use a regexp to do this matter: Regular expressions are useful to match patterns made of characters, but not patterns made of patterns.

To process an HTML string you need a proper *parser*: If it is XHTML, you can parse it straightforward through a DocumentBuilder. If not, you need to convert it first to XHTML through opensource library Tidy.

Through a parser you'll convert your HTML string to a Document object, which you shall process to traverse it, add or remove any nodes.

Comment: Thanks @little-santi for your idea.